# C# Using async await inside foreach to execute API

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there a way to use a `foreach()` to call an API multiple times with different parameters. Currently the code only executes the first item (itemOne) and not the rest of the items. I want to get back all the results and then exit the function.

The method that calls TestExecute() comes from the controller. I haven't shown controller method  since it only calls TestLogs. There are no errors being shown. Basically I want to loop through all three of the items to get the itemId and store it in the list. In this case it would call the API 3 times and store the results and only then do I want to exit this function.

```
    public class TestLogs
    {

        private readonly ITest _test;
        public TestLogs()
        {

            _test = new test();

        }

       private async Task<TestProjectsDto> GetProjectId()
       { 
            var date = new DateTime(2020, 04, 15);

            var sapProjectNum = new TestProjectsDto
            {
                Projects = new List<TestProjectDto>()
            };

            var list = new List<string>()
            {
                "itemOne",
                "itemTwo",
                "itemThree"
            };

            foreach (var divList in list)
            {
                var proIds = await _test.GetProjectItem(divList, date);

                if (proIds != null)
                {
                    sapProjectNum.Projects.AddRange(proIds.Projects);
                }
            }

            return sapProjectNum;
        }
        public async Task TestExecute()
        {
            // Where I call GetProjectId(); 
            var listProjectIds = GetProjectId();

            // etc 


        }

    }
}



public class TestService : ITest
{
        //etc 
    public async Task<TestProjectsDto> GetProjectOnSpecificDate(string divisionName, DateTime date)
    {
        var url = $"{test}/GetProjectOnSpecificDate.xsjs?TYPE=item={item}&Date={date:yyyy-MM-dd}";
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TestProjectsDto>().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return content;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this code executed and are there any exceptions caught? How do you know that the loop executes only once and that `itemTwo` and `itemThree` simply don't return any `proIds`?

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code. You should be looping over the list just fine. Have you tried stepped through it using a debugger to see what is going on?

Comment: Yes, it only goes through the loop once. Exits the function and says " Status: waiting for activation".

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance for posting code. The code as shown in the post should (assuming sensible implementation of `GetProjectItem` ) should behave exactly as you want.

Comment: @HJ1990 sounds like you also need to show how you call this function (as there is serious chance of you misunderstanding `async` completly)

Comment: I've updated the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Code looks fine. Just step through it in debugger and see what is going on.

Comment: It might just be me, but isn't the TestExecute method missing an await before GetProjectId();

Comment: You're right, I was missing the await before the GetProjectId(). Works now :) . Thanks !